# Compressing a directory of files with PHP

Tags: php, compression, backup

I am creating a php backup script that will dump everything from a database and save it to a file. I have been successful in doing that but now I need to take hundreds of images in a directory and compress them into one simple .tar.gz file.

What is the best way to do this and how is it done? I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this can help you http://codingbin.com/compressing-a-directory-of-files-with-php/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.2 or later, you could use the [Zip Library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)

and then do something along the lines of:

```
$images_dir = '/path/to/images';
//this folder must be writeable by the server
$backup = '/path/to/backup';
$zip_file = $backup.'/backup.zip';

if ($handle = opendir($images_dir))  
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) 
    {
        exit("cannot open <$zip_file>\n");
    }

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        $zip->addFile($images_dir.'/'.$file);
        echo "$file\n";
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
    echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
    $zip->close();
    echo 'Zip File:'.$zip_file . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kev for the answer. I just need to clarify one little thing: did you mean to ask if I had a version of PHP lower than 5.2 or higher than 5.2. I currently have 5.2.6. As I understand your answer, I will not be able to run this because I have a PHP version to high. Is this correct?

Comment: He means that you need a PHP version that's 5.2.0 or later, so you'll be fine.

Comment: Yeah sorry as Alexander says its for 5.2.0 or later

Comment: I just tried this and I get this error:<br>
Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in [...] on line 7. 
<br>What could cause this? I just contacted my web hosting provider to tell me if PHP is installed with the appropriate libraries.

Comment: That would suggest to me that your host doesnt support the ZipArchive class, thy would need to compile PHP with zip support by using the --enable-zip configure option (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)

Comment: Yes, that is what I think too. That is why I am contacting my hosting provider now.

Comment: Well, I finaly got this script to run. I just tried it on a different server. But it does not work. For some reason, the archive is not created. I do not get any errors, the status at the end is show as 0 and it accurately counts the number of files. I have searched high and low for the archive in the server, but I can't find it. I used the script exaclty how it is written except I changed the first line to: if ($handle = opendir('inmobiliarios')) {. All I did was remove the leading slash because the script could not find the directory.

Comment: The Zip should be in the directory with the images. Is the directory writable?

Comment: Ok, would it be possible to do this instead: have 2 directories (images and backup) and have the script outside of these directories. The script takes the files from the images dir and compresses them into one file in the backup dir. I changed the first line to inmobiliarios/ and the third line to backup/inmobiliarios_backup.zip but it still does not work.

Comment: ive updated the script a bit to do the above, you need to ensure that the backup directory is writeable though. If is isn't the script will still work but wont be able to save the zip and not give any errors

Comment: Thank you everybody for all the help. I finally go the script to work. All I had to do was change this line: $zip->addFile($file); to this: $zip->addFile('path/to/images/'.$file);

Comment: Its not saving the zip for me either, even with the new code. The directory is writable for sure as there are other things writing to it. It runs fine, just doesn't save the zip file.

Comment: @VinkoCM thanks for your last comment, that was the problem I was having. Perhaps the answer could get updated.

Comment: Should `if ($handle = opendir($images))` be `if ($handle = opendir($images_dir))`?

Comment: Showing name of files and name of zip file with status 0. so how it can be resolved? It's not making a zip file @David

Answer (score 14):

```
$archive_name = 'path\to\archive\arch1.tar';
$dir_path = 'path\to\dir';

$archive = new PharData($archive_name);
$archive->buildFromDirectory($dir_path); // make path\to\archive\arch1.tar
$archive->compress(Phar::GZ); // make path\to\archive\arch1.tar.gz
unlink($archive_name); // deleting path\to\archive\arch1.tar
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use something like this:

```
exec('tar -czf backup.tar.gz /path/to/dir-to-be-backed-up/');
```

Be sure to [heed the warnings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-notes) about using PHP's `exec()` function.

Comment: Is this code runs on a server which is disabled functions `exec`,`system`,`shell_exec`,`...`?

Answer (score 1):

My simple 2 lines PHP file by which I can create a backup ZIP file within a few seconds:

Just browse: http://mysiteurl.com/create-my-zip.php

```
<?php
/* PHP FILE NAME: create-my-zip.php */

echo exec('tar zcf my-backup.tar.gz mydirectory/*');

echo '...Done...';

?>
```

Simply upload this file into the server and browse directly.

Notes:

- 'mydirectory' ==> target directory relative to this PHP script;
- 'my-backup.tar.gz' ==> will be created at the same directory where this PHP file is uploaded;

Answer (score 1):

Chosen answer doesn't support recursion (subdirectories), so here you go:

```
<?
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(3600);


$main_path = 'folder2zip';
$zip_file = 'zipped.zip';

if (file_exists($main_path) && is_dir($main_path))  
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
        unlink($zip_file); // truncate ZIP
    }
    if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        die("cannot open <$zip_file>\n");
    }

    $files = 0;
    $paths = array($main_path);
    while (list(, $path) = each($paths))
    {
        foreach (glob($path.'/*') as $p)
        {
            if (is_dir($p)) {
                $paths[] = $p;
            } else {
                $zip->addFile($p);
                $files++;

                echo $p."<br>\n";
            }
        }
    }

    echo 'Total files: '.$files;

    $zip->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily gzip a folder using this command:

```
tar -cvzpf backup.tar.gz /path/to/folder
```

This command can be ran through phps system()-function.

Don't forget to escapeshellarg() all commands.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for you answer. How would this look like in php? Would it go something along the lines of:

system('tar -cvzpf my_backup.tar.gz /images_water/images_rivers/');

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me because my hosting provider has set security restrictions on exec/system commands.

Comment: This is very very bad solution. Running it will bear a new process which is a big waste.

Answer (score 0):

from @Martin Zvarík anwser. I had a small change!
This will help us compress all file (and all file in subfolder) to a zip file, but will not include root

ex:
root path

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\zip-this-folder.php
D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\index.php
D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\assets\...
D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\js\..
```

when call: zip-this-folder.php
it will output myapp.zip
myapp.zip have

```
- zip-this-folder.php
- index.php
- assets\...
- js\..
```

zip-this-folder.php:

```
echo $main_path = str_replace("\\", "/", __DIR__ );// get current folder, which call scipt
$zip_file = 'myapp.zip';

if (file_exists($main_path) && is_dir($main_path))  
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if (file_exists($zip_file)) {
        unlink($zip_file); // truncate ZIP
    }
    if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        die("cannot open <$zip_file>\n");
    }

    $files = 0;
    $paths = array($main_path);
    while (list(, $path) = each($paths))
    {
        foreach (glob($path.'/*') as $p)
        {
            if (is_dir($p)) {
                $paths[] = $p;
            } else {
                // special here: we remove root folder ("D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\") :D
                $new_filename = str_replace($main_path."/" , "", $p);
                $zip->addFile($p, $new_filename);
                $files++;

                echo $p."<br>\n";
            }
        }
    }

    echo 'Total files: '.$files;

    $zip->close();
}
```