# Downloading Large Numbers of Files with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, download

I have a situation where I need to download and compress a large amount of files from S3 (probably more than 2000) and then send them to be downloaded by the client. Each file is not all that big but it is a large operation for the server to accomplish.

I have already set up in such a way where I am processing this task on a worker environment and using streams with S3 to download the files and compress them. I am still finding that this is straining the server greatly when this job processes and sometimes causes "out of memory" errors.

Can anyone recommend a better way of handing this scenario? How can I download a large number of files from S3, combine them into a single archive, and then serve that archive to the customer efficiently?

I noticed that Dropbox itself doesn't allow you to download more than about 200 files at a time, is that the best way to attack this? To chunk the downloads?

Comment: just download the file in a folder and then compressing doesn't work?

Comment: there are MANY files. seems it is taking up a lot of memory to accomplish this task...

Comment: how do you know the file names to download? accessing the folder or you have it the list in your hands to call those files particularly?

Comment: The file keys are stored in the DB, so I know which ones I need. From what I have seen with S3, it isn't possible to compress an entire directory and download it so I have to go one by one.

Comment: [Guzzle allows async requests](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#async-requests) which might optimise the throughput you achieve. The AWS SDK v3 includes it out of the box so there's a good chance you can do async requests using that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Laravel: 
 $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $filename);
 copy('https://my-cdn.com/files/image.jpg', $tempImage);
 return response()->download($tempImage, $filename);
```

Download the files one by one, put them in a directory and then once you are done with download, compress the the folder using:

```
// Core php: 
$archive_name = 'path\to\archive\arch1.tar';
$dir_path = 'path\to\dir';

$archive = new PharData($archive_name);
$archive->buildFromDirectory($dir_path); // make path\to\archive\arch1.tar
$archive->compress(Phar::GZ); // make path\to\archive\arch1.tar.gz
unlink($archive_name); // deleting path\to\archive\arch1.tar
```

Compression code has been taken from: [Compressing a directory of files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048805/compressing-a-directory-of-files-with-php)

Comment: Yes, I was doing this. Seems to suck a lot of memory. Was wondering if there was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: what's the file size? it shouldn't suck the memory. I hope you are doing it via some backend process, not via url in the browser

Comment: The URL in the browser dispatches a job that processes on a worker environment. Each file size is small but when you add a lot of them up, the archive passes the 1gb size.